# Google Couldbuild - Prevent new logger

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

This is a bit of a weird question, but we use Google Cloudbuild and it seems like when looking at jobs, sometimes I get the old logger, and sometimes I get the new logger:

new logger:
[image]

I can't get a screenshot of the old logger as right now I am getting the new one.

I find the new logger unusable and unreadable. is there a way to disable it somehow? 
Maybe by changing a cookie or some values in JS?

Comment: When did it start? Currently there is no way to change them

Comment: it's been like that for at least a year, and it's a coin toss every day which logger we get. the "new one" is pretty annoying.

Comment: this is expected behavior since sometimes UI changes. Currently there is no way to disable it